# Score not incrementing in app

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, score isn't incrementing and the message I get when doing my own quiz is that I got 0 out of 3, when I've clicked all the right answers. Could anybody please take a quick look and tell me what I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int score;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    score = 0;

    final CheckedTextView check1 = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.Q1answerA);
    check1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            score++;
            check1.toggle();
            newActivity1();
        }
    });

    final CheckedTextView check2 = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.Q1answerB);
    check2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check2.toggle();
            newActivity1();
        }
    });

    final CheckedTextView check3 = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.Q1answerC);
    check3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check3.toggle();
            newActivity1();
        }
    });
}

public void newActivity1() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public int getScore1(){
    return this.score;
}
}
```

newActivity

```
public class NewActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
int score;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new1);

    score = 0;

    final CheckedTextView check1 = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.Q2answerA);
    check1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check1.toggle();
            newActivity2();
        }
    });

    final CheckedTextView check2 = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.Q2answerB);
    check2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            score++;
            check2.toggle();
            newActivity2();
        }
    });

    final CheckedTextView check3 = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.Q2answerC);
    check3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check3.toggle();
            newActivity2();
        }
    });

}

public void newActivity2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity1.this, NewActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public int getScore2() {
    return this.score;
}
}
```

newActivity

```
public class NewActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
int score;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new2);

    score = 0;

    final CheckedTextView check1 = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.Q3answerA);
    check1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            score++;
            check1.toggle();
            newActivity3();
        }
    });

    final CheckedTextView check2 = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.Q3answerB);
    check2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check2.toggle();
            newActivity3();
        }
    });

    final CheckedTextView check3 = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.Q3answerC);
    check3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check3.toggle();
            newActivity3();
        }
    });

}
public void newActivity3() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity2.this, NewActivity3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public int getScore3() {
    return this.score;
}
}
```

newActivity

```
public class NewActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
    int score;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new3);

    score = 0;

    score();
    textScore();
}

public void score() {
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    NewActivity1 ac1 = new NewActivity1();
    NewActivity2 ac2 = new NewActivity2();

    if (main.getScore1() == 1) {
        score++;
    }
    if (ac1.getScore2() == 1) {
        score++;
    }
    if (ac2.getScore3() == 1) {
        score++;
    }
}

public int getScore() {
    return this.score;
}

public void textScore() {
    if (getScore() == 3) {
        TextView score3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score3);
        score3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (getScore() == 2) {
        TextView score2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score2);
        score2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (getScore() == 1) {
        TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score1);
        score1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (getScore() == 0) {
        TextView score0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score0);
        score0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: It appears that you are actually creating a new activity after the click... complete with its own separate 'score' variable.  Meanwhile, your score function also creates a new activity, with score=0.

Comment: I would like to suggest that you should not be creating a new activity for each question.  That's a bit of overkill.  Also, while you have been trying things out, and that is certainly useful, I would not recommend hardcoding the activity quiz answers.  A better idea might be to use a "Question" class with a question string and an correct answer index (1,2,3).  Then, when the user presses a button, reconfigure your activity with the next question.  Heck, you might even store the questions/answers in a resource data file (eg., XML or JSON)

Comment: StartActivityForResult can be the solution

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! I'm not sure how to go about it though Jamie so I'm kinda still stuck here. :/